# How to add dynamic header to generated PDF document

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, tuespechkin

Im using [TuesPechkin](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin) to ceate Pdfs from dynamic Html.
The body is easy as it can take a Html string, the header & footer however only take Urls.
I have them stored locally atm as html, I can bring them in to the document, but without any dynamic content.

Is there a way to use Razor or similar to bring a value in like this -

```
var document = new HtmlToPdfDocument
{
    GlobalSettings = new GlobalSettings(),
    Objects = 
    {
        new ObjectSettings 
        { 
            HtmlText = "<p>Some Html</p>",
            Footer = new FooterSetting { PageUrl = "file://C:/file.cshtml?Name=name" }
        }
    }
};
```

Html looking something like

```
<html>
    <p>Name: @Request["name"]</p>
</html>
```

The project is just a class library so I believe it's missing some aspects needed to run razor?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 1):

You can try rendering the razor code to a string, then saving it as a file and finally export the file to PDF.

Sometime like this:

**Razor to String**

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

**Export to PDF**

```
public void MyPDFExport()
{
    string url = @"d:\Foo.html";
    string html = RenderRazorViewToString("File", "myName");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(url, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(html));

    var document = new HtmlToPdfDocument
    {
        GlobalSettings = new GlobalSettings(),
        Objects = 
        {
            new ObjectSettings 
            { 
                HtmlText = "<p>Some Html</p>",
                FooterSettings = new FooterSettings { HtmlUrl = url }
            }
        }
    };
    IConverter converter =
        new ThreadSafeConverter(
            new RemotingToolset<PdfToolset>(
                new Win32EmbeddedDeployment(
                    new TempFolderDeployment())));

    byte[] result = converter.Convert(document);
}
```

**View File.cshtml**

```
@model string

<html>
    <p>Name: @Model</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer. We wanted to avoid saving anything physically other than the pdf (should have specified this). Opted for setting up a web server to run the razor in the end

Comment: @Tamzoid I think you cant do that without saving the html file (once rendered) on your server. What is the problem with saving it in temp file and then delete it once the pdf is created?

Comment: Why would you need to save the html page? Im just using a controller and viewbag then specifying the value i want to display in the url. No specific reason, others on my team seem to frown upon it

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question. But I spend a couple of days to figure out how to make TuesPechkin headers truly dynamic. As I have a very long data table which spreads to several PDF pages, I need to have header, which has column headers repeated on every page. But because first page has a summary on the top of the page and the table data starts below the summary, I need to alter header that is shown on very first page. HtmlUrl in HeaderSettings is an URL, which is the same on every page of generated PDF, so I need workaround which is not documented on TuesPechkin software.

**PDF generation:**

```
using TuesPechkin;
...
private static StandardConverter _converter;
...

string headerHtml = $"http://127.0.0.1/api/GetPdfHeader?"+
   $"accountId={AccountId}&accName={AccountHolderName}" +
   $"&dateGen={DateGenerated}&range={DateRange}"+
   $"&tagFilter={FilterVal}&filters={FiltersUsed}";
string html = ""; // main page content (long HTML table) is here
            // 
//Configure the converter
if (_converter == null)
{
   _converter = new ThreadSafeConverter(
      new RemotingToolset<PdfToolset>(new WinAnyCPUEmbeddedDeployment(
         new TempFolderDeployment())));
}
var header = new HeaderSettings()
{
   HtmlUrl = headerHtml.Replace(" ", "%20")
};
byte[] pdfBytes = _converter.Convert(new HtmlToPdfDocument {
   GlobalSettings = global,
   Objects = {
      new ObjectSettings { HtmlText = html, HeaderSettings = header }
   }
});
// Use these PDF bytes array to save PDF or pass it back to your code
```

**Header** is generated by an HTTP call. Implementation:

```
     public System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage GetPdfHeader(string accountId, string accName, 
string dateGen, string range, string tagFilter, string filters)
  {
     var request = this.Request;
     var queryString = request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
     int page = 0;
     if (queryString!=null && queryString["page"] != null)
     {
        page = System.Convert.ToInt32(queryString["page"]);
        int totalPages = System.Convert.ToInt32(queryString["topage"]);
     }

     string html = ""; // Generate HTML for header here
     // Update html with passed parameters accountId, accName, dateGen etc.

     if (page == 1)
     {
        // remove table header on first page
        html = UpdateHtml(html); // modify
     }

     var resp = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
     {
        Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(html, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")
     };
     return resp;
  }
```

Note, that inside we have a "page" variable, passed with every HTTP request, which can be used in custom HTML generation. This code will be called every time a new page is added to PDF when TuesPechkin generates it. For example if you have 5 pages, it will be called 5 times. It also has "topage" parameter which stands for totalPages.